# The commutator of scalar field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, integration

I have a real scalar field which is given by the propagator as:

$$[\phi(x),\phi(y) ] =\int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{2E_0} (\exp(-ip\cdot (x-y)) -\exp (ip\cdot (x-y)))$$

And I am asked to show that this equals $$\frac{1}{4\pi r} \partial_r J_0(m\sqrt{t^2-r^2})$$

Where $J_0$ is bessel function of order 0, $t=x^0-y^0$, and $r=|x^i-y^i|$.

I am clueless as to how to show this. I mean the first integral is an integral with integrand $2\imath \sin(p\cdot(x-y))$.

Anyone care to enlighten me, or me a thorough reference for this calculation?

Comment: Looks like the commutator you wrote equals zero. There is probably some typo...

Comment: @Trimok: I don't know, the two exponents seem equal, so their difference vanishes, before any integration. Or am I missing something?

Comment: The second term is $\exp(ip\cdot (x-y))$

Comment: I edited my post to correct this typo.

Comment: @akhmeteli : You were correct : I did not see the typo...

Comment: Looks like the question is very similar to http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30220/commutator-of-scalar-fields , if not a duplicate.

Comment: Refer to Srednicki QFT Formula (4.12) and problem 4.1.

Comment: This question is ill-posed at present (v4). What is $E_0$, and how does it relate to $m$?

Comment: Needless to say, I closed this because it appears to be a no-effort homework question. I would be interested to hear from the reopen voters, perhaps in [chat], about why they disagree.

Comment: @David Z: I did vote to reopen, and I appreciate that technically it is indeed "a no-effort homework question". However, I felt this is a good, non-trivial, and relatively fundamental question, so I thought some hints might be advisable (not for my own benefit though:-))

Comment: @akhmeteli Ah, I see. The thing is, no-effort homework questions at all levels are against our policy. While your votes are of course yours to cast as you see fit, I think it does the site a disservice when you vote in a way that contradicts one of our well-established policies like that. If you think the policy should be changed so questions like this would be allowed, then you should definitely offer your input on [meta], on any of the questions where the homework policy is currently under discussion (or a new one, if appropriate).

Comment: @David Z: I don't know, maybe I am not quite clear about the current policy (or about English:-)). There is the following phrase at http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic : "Some kinds of questions should not be asked here: "Do my homework"-type physics questions"... So there is "should not" there, not "must not". I felt this question was useful for the site. You disagree, and your opinion certainly prevails.

Comment: @akhmeteli in this case I believe you can take "should not" to be a more polite way of saying "must not." But I would be happy to discuss this in [chat] so we can clarify our understandings to each other. All these guidelines should ultimately come from the community (they are not imposed by the moderators), and you are part of that community, so if you disagree with something, your opinion certainly deserves to be taken into account.

Comment: [Relevant meta discussion](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/5284/8563).